# Is it legitimate to assign values to non-array objects with braces?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I discovered by accident that this works in the body of a program:(currently using g++ 5.2.0)

```
Vector4  pos;  
pos = {0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
```

The Vector4 class declares this data as named variables:

```
double  t, x, y, z;
```

not as an array, and has no auto conversion cnstrs.

I guess memory storage is contiguous, so the compiler can figure out what to do. But is this legitimate usage, or can unallocated memory get used, or maybe some other gotchas possible?

Comment: It's aggregate initialization.

Comment: It's a C++11 feature. You haven't provided the full definition of `Vector4` so I can only say that it is probably safe.

Comment: @JamesRoot Hmmm, it looks weird, I don't think it is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), as it is an assignment. Then I wonder how is the rhs converted to a `Vector4` type from a list-init.

Comment: @vsoftco I _think_ it is using aggregate initialization to construct a `Vector4` and then assign it to `pos`.

Comment: @JamesRoot Yes, that's probably what happens, it is equivalent to `x = Vector4{...};`. Also making the object non-aggregate (e.g., defining an explicit copy ctor) results in a compile-time error. I'm trying to find some relevant citation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment)

> If the right operand is a braced-init-list
>
> - the expression E1 = {} is equivalent to E1 = T{}, where T is the type of E1.
> - the expression E1 = {E2} is equivalent to E1 = T{E2}, where T is the type of E1.
>
> For class
> types, the syntax E = {e1, e2, e3} generates a call to the assignment
> operator with the braced-init-list as the argument, which then selects
> the appropriate assignment operator following the rules of overload
> resolution

Hence your code is equivalent to

```
pos = Vector4{0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
```

The compiler performs [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of a temporary, then, using the assignment operator of `Vector4`, assigns the resulting object to `pos`.

The usage is perfectly safe. Note that if your `Vector4` had been a non-aggregate (e.g., had user-defined constructors), then aggregate initialization wouldn't work (i.e., you'd have got a compile-time error). So the fact that the code compiles means you're safe.

Comment: It's not called copy-list-initialization, it's just a call to the assignment operator.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I use the wording of [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization) (which is not the standard, I know :) ).

Comment: The wording on the list-initialization page is not what you quoted. The [assignment operator page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment) has no mention of the word list-initialization.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I thought they are related, as #10 specifies a call to the assignment operator. Or do you think it is only relevant for *overloaded assignment operators*, and not built-in? I have to say that the reference is not completely clear.

Comment: Initialization is not the same as assignment, the only thing being done here is assignment. Your answer is correct except for calling it copy-list-initialization.

Comment: Sorry I will rephrase.  The `E1` is assigned, not initialized. `T` isdirect-(list-)initialized;  the copy-list-initialization refers to the parameter of `E1.operator=` . Aggregate initialization is a flavour of list initialization.  Later where you say "of a rvalue", should be "of a temporary". There's no rvalue denoting that temporary.

Comment: @M.M, 0x499602D2 thanks, edited. I removed the copy-list-init altogether, as it creates more confusion than clarity. I don't even know if the term is standard.

Comment: *copy-list-initialization* is standard.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, thanks for explaining this.  A trivial test prog shows the default cnstr called twice followed by the assignment operator.  These are:

```
Vector4() : t(0.0), x(0.0), y(0.0), z(0.0) {}
```

and

```
Vector4 const &operator =(const Vector4 &v) {
    if(this != &v) {t=v.t; x=v.x; y=v.y; z=v.z;}
    return *this;  
}
```

Comment: That's indeed what happens. You have one default ctor call in `Vector4  pos;`, then another call invoked by the temporary's ctor `pos = { ... };`, and lastly followed by the assignment operator.